# jQuery UI AutomComplete - Request aborted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I noticed that jQuery UI Auto-Complete will "abort" some HTTP requests if user is typing fast. Will those request still hit the service? If it is, is there anyway to reduce the requests being send besides setting delay or minimum typed in letter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible by setting `delay` on your `autocomplete` definition.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ delay: 500 });
```

> The delay in milliseconds between when a keystroke occurs and when a
>   search is performed. A zero-delay makes sense for local data (more
>   responsive), but can produce a lot of load for remote data, while
>   being less responsive.

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay

Comment: I think my question is are there other approaches BESIDES setting delay.